# 3'panels view for iPad like in the Mail.app for Mac Os

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to implement 3'panels view for iPad like in the Mail.app for Mac Os:

[image]

It seems that we can not put SplitviewController inside SplitviewController, any other ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `UISplitViewController` to do something that resembles a `UISplitViewController`. 3 `UIViewControllers` are more than enough. You can a create a 4th one to host the other 3 and then use it as mediator between the other 3.